# how to add precompiled binaries to a python project (cloud-functions python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have to deploy a python function to GCP. The libraries I want to use a library ([USD](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD) by Pixar specifically) which needs I need to build myself. To make the library accessible I need to make changes to $PATH an $PYTHONPATH.

So the problem is that I have to include everything in one project to deploy the function and I don't know where to start.

I have tried appending to PYTHONPATH on run-time but it gives no module error. Also I have no idea how can I change PATH variable to be able to use executables inside usd/bin folder

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('lib/python') # relative path.
```

Comment: Exactly what's produced by the build script? You say "but no luck", but what's the error? How are you trying to use the library in your function?

Comment: Basically I just want to know how do I include precompiled binaries in python project. Help material or anything. I want to use [gltf2usd](https://github.com/kcoley/gltf2usd) which requires usd

Comment: There's lots of things that could be going wrong here, and most folks here aren't familiar with USD. You're saying "binaries" but is there a Python module as well? What exactly is the error you get when you try to use `gltg2usd`?

Comment: I don't exactly why is it like that but USD has optional support for python but you still need the actual binaries. I think I have to edit system path with python : (os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '').

Comment: I added this question because it seems like a common problem. Lots of libraries come with executables. Do they all edit the PATH variable at run-time? BTW Thanksfor the help! :)

Comment: Most libraries that ship with executables are installable via pip, so they know where their executables are located. Most libraries don't suggest that users modify their PYTHONPATH, it's generally discouraged.